# Fetching XCOM returns None value in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to access XCOM value while learning Airflow, but every time, I get None returned.

Below is the DAG code. I have also set the dependency, still no luck.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'ashish',
    'retries': '2',
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}

# Basic Python Function

"""
def greet():
    print("This is an example of the Python Operator DAG.")

# Python Function Accepting Parameters


def parameter_greet(name):
    print(f"Hi {name}")
"""
# Python Function returning value


def get_name():
    return 'Ashish'


def get_name_xcom(ti):
    name_xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_name')
    print(f"Hi {name_xcom}. This was pulled from XCOM.")


with DAG(
    dag_id='Python_Operator',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Example for Python Operator',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 30, 2),
    schedule_interval='@daily'

) as dag:
    """
    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Greet',
        python_callable=greet
    )

    task2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Greet_Parameter',
        python_callable=parameter_greet,
        op_kwargs={'name': 'Ashish'}
    )
    """
    task3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='XCOM_Example',
        python_callable=get_name
    )

    task4 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Greet_with_XCOM',
        python_callable=get_name_xcom
    )

    # task1
    # task2
    task3 >> task4
```

Tried setting the value using ti.xcom.push and then retrieving it using ti.xcom.pull but that is not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `task_ids` value in `xcom_pull()` should be the actual `task_id` of the task which pushed the XCom rather than the name of the callable.

You'll need to update your `get_name_xcom` your function to this:

```py
def get_name_xcom(ti):
    name_xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='XCOM_Example')
    print(f"Hi {name_xcom}. This was pulled from XCOM.")
```